# Continously autosave data after selecting from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I found the code below [Autosave Selection Without Submit Button](http://jiansenlu.blogspot.my/2014/11/ajax-autosave-selection-without-submit.html#undefined?motigredir=1), and edited a few code at the index.php and save_status.php page. This code manage to save the selected answer in the database but it can only be save one by one.

For example referring to the image Output below, after I select the status for ID no 1, I need to refresh the page before I can select the status for ID no 2,3 and so on.

Is there anything that can be add or edit to my code so that I can continuously select the status for every ID without refreshing or anything.

index.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select.status').on('change',function () {
            var decision = $(this).val();
            var id = $('td.myid').html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "save_status.php",
                data: {decision : decision, id: id },
                success: function(msg) {
                    $('#autosavenotify').text(msg);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>

<div id='autosavenotify'></div>
<td class='myid'><?php echo $row ['id']; ?> </td>   
<td>
    <select class='status' required>
        <option value='' selected> Pending </option>
        <option value='1'> Approve </option>
        <option value='2'> Reject </option>
    </select>";
</td>
```

save_status.php

```
$decision=$_POST['decision'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$query = "UPDATE leaves_apply SET status='$decision' WHERE id='$id'";
$resource = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Output
[image]

Comment: The "but it can only be save one by one" suggests that there is an error occurring that is preventing further saves. The line var id = $('td.myid').html(); doesn't look right - what is this value returning? Is the database actually updated?

Comment: @jeff yes, the line vard id = $('td.myid').html(); return the id value and the database updated. After I update for ID no 1, it updates. Then I would like to update for ID no 2, nothing happens. It doesn't update anymore

Comment: Add the jQuery error/fail function to your result and show this in the autosavenotify div. What is the message?

Comment: @Jeff sorry I don't really get what you mean. Can you please explain further?